# How to install jdk for offline compile?

Tags: java

I want to compile java offline.

I have project on PC, will just copy and make small changes to it, and test it, when I am away from home.

Doesnt need to be an IDE. Not even code editor. Just a working compiler.

No need to be an app apk, a method to install it thru usb adb would suffice.

I am looking for a 100% free option too.

Comment: Why not just remote to your PC? As for what you asked, I only know [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui), but given I have not looked into programming on phones further, there could be more choices.

Comment: @andyyan because of the cost of the mobile data connection. I am looking for a 100% free option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling and running java applications from android terminal?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/94116/compiling-and-running-java-applications-from-android-terminal)

Comment: @andrewt. My goal was to not need any app to compile from inside android, so I could just run javac. I found that oracle has an arm jdk, still have to test it tho

Answer (score 0):

If your project only uses Command Line Interface, and only uses sub-packages from `java.lang` , then you can try "TERMUX" android app, it's a terminal emulator, so you should be familiar with linux terminals.

As of now , it doesn't have the entire JDK, but I can provide you a package that has basic tools like `javac` and `jar`, 
that you could use with termux.
**BUT** if your project uses AWT classes, this method won't help.